# Current vs time under fixed bias in semiconductor

Tags: current, semiconductors

Could someone please tell me how would the Current vs time curve of a pn-junction diode would look like under constant applied bias? Is the current going to go to zero as time gets large?

Thanks

Comment: Quite likely it will go to zero as time gets large if the applied forward voltage is more than a volt or two.

Comment: are you applying a constant voltage or constant current as bias? My bad. Obviously you meant constant volts.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the power supply. current may fade down to zero if we use a battery. If supply is strong enough then current will remain constant for constant applied bias.

Comment: A failing battery would not be a "fixed bias" like op asked about.